# Function in Django Views causing others to throw 404 errors

Tags: django, django-views

I have a weird bug where one view:

```
def view_dashboard (request, username):
    # If no such user exists raise 404
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        print(user)
    except:
        raise Http404

    template = 'testingland/dashboard.html'
    return render (request, template)
```

Is causing others to throw 404 errors when I visit their urls. Note: I get a 404 when I visit the above view's connected url but also when I visit another view's url. For instance, visiting the url associated with this view also throws a 404:

```
def write_description(request):
    return render(request, 'testingland/write_description.html')
```

Here are my url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.cafes_home, name='cafes_home'),
    path('', views.index_2, name='cafes_home'),
    path('venue/<int:venue_id>/', views.venue_page, name='venue_page'),
    url('electra/cafe_list/', views.cafe_list.as_view(), name='cafe_list'),
    url('electra/marker_info/', views.marker_info, name='marker_info'),
    url('electra/info_box/', views.info_box, name='info_box'),
    url('electra/new_marker/', views.new_marker, name='new_marker'),
    url('electra/broadsheet_scraper/', views.broadsheet_scraper, name='broadsheet_scraper'),
    url('electra/get_cafe/', views.get_cafe, name='get_cafe'),
    url('add_cafe', views.add_cafe, name='add_cafe'), 
    url('add_description', views.add_description, name='add_description'), 
    url('add_image', views.add_image, name='add_image'), 
    url('add_broadsheet', views.add_broadsheet, name='add_broadsheet'), 
    url('add_broadsheet', views.add_broadsheet, name='add_broadsheet'), 
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('users', views.users, name='users'),
    path('<username>', views.view_dashboard, name='view_dashboard'),
    url('electra/get_users/', views.get_users, name='get_users'),
    path('electra/getUserMarkers/', views.getUserMarkers, name='getUserMarkers'),

    #auth
    path('signup', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login', auth.views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', auth.views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    #placelist
    path('write_description', views.write_description, name='write_description'),
    # path('write_image', views.write_image, name='write_image'),
    path('broadsheet', views.broadsheet, name='broadsheet'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.DetailList.as_view(), name='detail_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/update', views.UpdateList.as_view(), name='update_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete', views.DeleteList.as_view(), name='delete_list'),
]
```

Here is the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard
Raised by:  testingland.views.view_dashboard
```

Comment: Your pattern `'<username>'` matches the patterns `'signup'`, etc. below it. Hence the view `view_dashboard` is used for all of them. Design your urls well or atleast order them well.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm a little unsure what you mean by the patterns matching, they all look different to me. I am fairly new to Django.

Comment: When you write `'<username>'` it basically means in this place there would be a string which we would capture to pass as an argument to the view. `'signup'`, `'login'` match the criteria of being a string (match the regex `[^/]+` which is used to match for strings in urls) so in simpler words there can be a user with a username `login`, etc. and since pattern is first in the order it matches those strings and the view is used for them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I moved the offending URL to the bottom of the ``urls.py`` file and it fixed the error. Feels a bit hacky, but I will do some more learning on this aspect of Django to optimise things. Thanks

Comment: I would advice to design your urls in a better way, for example instead of `'<username>'` try using `'user/<username>'`, it is more descriptive and there is an extra prefix preventing `signup` etc. from matching this url. Of course there can still be some issues due to some other url patterns etc. but if you design all your patterns in a good manner such things won't happen.